# how to develop DICOM Editor in asp.net

Tags: editor, dicom

i wanted to develop a DICOM Image editor in Asp.net
are there any library available for that.
or can i do something like
create an Jpeg from DICOM editor. edit the same image with lines or shapes and convert it back to DICOM Image file is that possible? if yes how?

i am new to DICOM. hence please help me to understand the DICOM.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of DICOM libraries for .NET. Refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287127/net-dicom-libraries) for more info.

UPDATED: another [one](https://github.com/rcd/fo-dicom)

As far as an ASP.NET viewer - what do you want this viewer to do. In other words, what is the target audience? Is it mobile users? Then silverlight, wcf and flash are out - the most used web-based larger-screen mobile device is the iPad, which supports none of those technologies. Is it desktop users? Flash could be the answer then, the install-base is quite high, and Flash has good support for a variety of image formats.

Do you need this viewer to be diagnostic-grade? In other words, do you need 16 bit window/level? cine loop for ultrasounds at the correct frequency? If yes, then you'll need to figure out some of this yourself. Existing mobile tools aren't so great at some of the above (specifically 16 bit grayscale).

HTML5 has some of the above capabilities, and is mobile-friendly. Anyway, start with the intended use for this tool, and that will lead you into a specific direction based on the requirements you come up with!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good place to get started:

[Medical Image Format FAQ - DICOM Information Sources](http://www.dclunie.com/medical-image-faq/html/part8.html)

Answer (score 0):

An open-source library that could be suitable for ASP.NET development is [mdcm](https://github.com/rcd/mdcm) that allows you to develop Silverlight assemblies that could be used from your web application.

There is also a successor to *mdcm* denoted [fo-dicom](https://github.com/rcd/fo-dicom), however I am not sure whether *fo-dicom* currently is applicable to Silverlight.